# URL hacking - can you calculate populated values? and save?

Tags: urlhacking, url

I am trying to accomplish the following requirement with URL hacking:
"Create an event associated to a parent case with some prepopulated fields"

There are some challenges that I am facing

- Can the activity record be also saved? (I don't want to end up on edit page)
- Can the activity dates be calculated like this: Start = [Created date - 20], End = [Activity Created date (time when the button is clicked)]

> ```
> /00U/e?what_id={!Case.Id}
> &retURL=/{!Case.Id}
> &cancelURL=/{!Case.Id}
> &evt5=Meeting with a client
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL Hacking is not supported by Salesforce.  I would suggest you use Publisher actions instead of URL Hacking.

Here are some guides for the same

http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/17/en-us/sfdc/pdf/actions_impl_guide.pdf

http://thewizardnews.com/2014/01/08/great-url-hack-meet-the-chatter-publisher-action/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the client don't want to use chatter yet so I cannot utilize publisher actions.

Comment: Okay, about the answers for your questions.  1) Cannot save the page directly.  Unless you use a VF Page (with an action method) with parameters passed.  2) Yes possible.  But do check the date formats, thats the tricky part.